# Deleting part of string in php using str_replace

Tags: php

I have a little issue with deleting a part of string using php.
Let me get you a little bit into problem, I have vlariable "column1text" in which is text string endered into < textarea >, but that does not matter. I want to remove all HTML tags from this string since they are doing problems sometimes. For example: When this string contains < /body > or < /table > it will do a lot of unwanted mess. So I want to get these tags away.

I am using `$column1text = str_replace("TEXT TO REMOVE", "", $column1text);` and it works, but I want to make function for it (optionaly if you know easier way, just tell me, I'll be glad).

I am using this function:
`function remove($removetext)
{
    $column1text = str_replace($removetext, "", $column1text);
}`

And I am using it like this:
`remove("TEXT TO REMOVE");`

What am I doing wrong? (I am sure it's something pretty silly, but I cannot find it!)

P.S. I am totally sorry about my English, it must sound stupid, but I had no other idea than asking you.

Answer (score 4):

You can either pass in `$column1text` as reference, or have your function returns the modified text (which I prefer)

```
 function remove($column1text, $removetext) {
   return str_replace($removetext, "", $column1text);
 }

$column1text = remove($column1text, '<span>');
```

Comment: Thank you! I am so glad it works :-) Only... Is that `'<span'>` or `'<span>'`? Because `>` is away from rest... Is that right or missclick?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing by value, when you actually need to be passing by reference. If you don't know what the difference is I suggest reading up a little on it.

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

edit:

In a nutshell, whenever you pass a function a parameter, that function makes a copy of whatever it was passed, so when that parameter is manipulated in the function, it manipulates the copy and not the passed object itself.

When a function has a parameter passed by reference, then it actually has access to the object that was passed itself. That means anything you do to manipulate that object also affects the object outside of the function (since its not just a copy of it you are working with).

Comment: Is this your attempt at answering the question?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No, I hit submit too early by accident. I edited to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell interpreter that you want to use global variable, because now it sees it as local variable (within your function). To do this you just need to use global keyword:

```
function remove($removetext) { 
    global $column1text;
    $column1text = str_replace($removetext, "", $column1text); 
}
```

you can read more about it here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Though it works, I would recommend staying away from global variables.